# Converting string hexadecmials to unsigned char (BYTE) in C

Tags: c++, c

I want to convert the hexadecimal string value `0x1B6` to `unsigned char` - where it will store the value in the format `0x1B`, `0x60` We had achieved the scenarios in C++, but C doesn't support `std::stringstream`.

The following code is C++, how do I achieve similar behavior in C?

```
char byte[2];
std::string hexa;
std::string str = "0x1B6" // directly assigned the char* value in to string here 
int index =0;
unsigned int i;

for(i = 2; i < str.length(); i++) {
    hexa = "0x"

    if(str[i + 1] !NULL) {
        hexa = hexa + str[i] + str[i + 1];
        short temp;

        std::istringstream(hexa) >> std::hex >> temp;
        byte[index] = static_cast<BYTE>(temp);
    } else {
        hexa = hexa+ str[i] + "0";
        short temp;
        std::istringstream(hexa) >> std::hex >> temp;
        byte[index] = static_cast<BYTE>(temp);
    }
}
```

```
output:
byte[0] --> 0x1B
byte[1]-->  0x60
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user is asking SO to do his work for them. There is no attempt to solve the issue themselves.

Comment: we tried many scenarios but nothing seems to be working out since i am new to c . i don't have huge knowledge on this .
Tried to concatenate the char* pointer but it doesn't seems to be working .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your solution is very efficient. But disregarding that, with C you would use `strtol`. This is an example of how to achieve something similar:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *hex_string = "0x1B60";
    long hex_as_long = strtol(hex_string, NULL, 16);
    printf("%lx\n", hex_as_long);

    // From right to left
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(&hex_string[2]); i += 2) {
        printf("%x\n", (hex_as_long >> (i * 4)) & 0xff);
    }

    printf("---\n");

    // From left to right
    for(int i = strlen(&hex_string[2]) - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        printf("%x\n", (hex_as_long >> (i * 4)) & 0xff);
    }
}
```

So here we get the full value as a `long` inside `hex_as_long`. We then print the whole long with the first print and the individual bytes inside the second for loop. We are shifting multiples of 4 bits because one hex digit (`0xf`) covers exactly 4 bits of data.

To get the bytes or the long printed to a string rather than to stdout (if that is what you want to achieve), you can use `strprintf` or `strnprintf` in a similar way to how `printf` is used, but with a variable or array as destination.

This solution scans whole bytes (`0xff`) at a time. If you need to handle one hex digit (`0xf`) at a time you can divide all the operations by two and mask with `0xf` instead of `0xff`.

Comment: it will be providing the output from LSB ( i.e if i give input like 1b6 , it gives  b6, 1  --> my scenario need  to be in MSB --> where it need to be 0x1b and 0x60

Comment: To flip it, just reverse the for loop -  or reverse it when you store it in the array.

Comment: @Vinooooo I modified the answer so it shows two solutions (from left to right and from right to left)